# How to receive shown.bs.collapse event from Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm unable to receive the `shown.bs.collapse` event from Bootstrap 3.3.6.  I've instrumented my `bootstrap.js` to make sure the event is being fired where I think it is:

```
this.$element.trigger('shown.bs.collapse')
console.log("triggered shown.bs.collapse on #" + this.$element.attr("id"))
```

In my document ready, I've tried registering for the event using both jQuery and pure JS:

```
$('.panel-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    console.log("listener called");
});
```

...or...

```
var panels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel-collapse");
for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; ++i) {
    console.log("adding event listener to #" + panels[i].getAttribute("id"));
    panels[i].addEventListener("shown.bs.collapse", function () {
        console.log("listener called");
    });
}
```

The JS version logs the same element ID that is logged when the event is fired in `bootstrap.js`, proving that I'm attaching the listener to the correct element.  But it's never called.

Even stranger, this all works in jsfiddle, but not when we copy the code into the application.  I'm thinking some package version or setting is screwed up somewhere.  What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089457/are-jquery-events-usables-with-dom-addeventlistener), you cannot use ".addEventListener" for custom jQuery events (e.g. "shown.bs.collapse").

I cannot say why the jQuery ".on" version wouldn't work, though.